# SSL Certificate error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, webautomation, puppeteer

I´m having an issue with puppeteer.
So what I want to do is to launch a website and login. However, this website tries to load a resource which is blocked because its insecure. After running the code I get this error message and the code stops running:

```
(node:11684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: SSL Certificate error: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
(node:11684) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function Login(username, password){
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://shop.adidas.ae/en/customer/account/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
  /*await page.type(username);
  await page.focus('#pass');
  await page.type(password);
  await page.click('#send2');*/
  await browser.close();
}

Login('xxx', 'xxx');
```

This is what the chrome consule puts out:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

My enviroment:
Latest Puppeteer version / Windows 10

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set `ignoreHTTPSErrors: true`. Beware: this will ignore all SSL errors.

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function Login(username, password){
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://shop.adidas.ae/en/customer/account/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
  /*await page.type(username);
  await page.focus('#pass');
  await page.type(password);
  await page.click('#send2');*/
  await browser.close();
}

Login('xxx', 'xxx');
```

Comment: And yet, that still opens a browser that shows "This site can’t provide a secure connection" instead of ignoring the cert entirely and just doing what it needs to =S